# c# save contents of IE browser as html

Tags: c#, .net, html, internet-explorer

I have an Internet Explorer window open. The title of this window will always be "test123"
how do I save the source of the contents of the window as an HTML file?

Please note that the process should not be to open a URL and read the HTML into a variable. I absolutely HAVE TO do it the way I described since I need to login to a site to be able to view the HTML that I want to save.

**if it makes it easier to do this through my winform and putting a webbrowser control on it, that is fine as well.

Comment: Not saying you can't do this, but you could also programmatically login to the site as well.

Comment: @daniel understood, but i do not need this functionality

Comment: Do you mean the browser as a control in your app?  Or are you trying to attach to the IE process and obtain the contents of the browser window?  It's a world of difference in degree of difficulty.

Comment: @that yes trying to attach to the IE process

Comment: @that i can do it in my app as well - can u help me with this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can attach to virtually any Windows app, using managed code and the [UI Automation classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747327.aspx).  Not a lot of people know about this stuff.

Microsoft shipped a class library and runtime that allows applications to automate other Windows on the system.  You can do things like click buttons, read textboxes, activate menus, and so on.  [Here's a quick intro](http://blog.functionalfun.net/2009/06/introduction-to-ui-automation-with.html).

It should be relatively simple to attach to an IE Window, and then programmatically tickle the File...Save As... menu option.

I did this the other day for a Paint.NET app.  It took much less time that I thought it would.

---

But I agree it's probably easier to use a WebBrowser control in a regular app, to programmatically retrieve content.  You could also use the System.Net.WebClient class to do it, if you don't need to show the HTML content.

Answer (score 0):

If you embed a WebBrowser control inside of your WinForm you can do this:

```
webBrowser1.Navigate("http://StackOverflow.com");
string pageHtml = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("html")[0].InnerHtml;
```

This will return all of the HTML in the page navigated to.